# Dlang - Is there a way to embed objects in objects?

Tags: memory-management, d, memory-layout

According to the D specification all classes are accessed by reference which would mean that the following class would be layed out in memory as follows.

Pseudocode:

```d
class A
{
    public int c;
    public B b;
}
```

Memory layout of an object of type A:

```
4 bytes | int c

(4/8) bytes | address of b
```

Is there a way to create a class that would embed b directly in A instead of having a reference? Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scoped turns out to be better than I thought, you can also use emplace which is a bit more cumbersome in this simple case but may come in handy:

```d
class A {
    import std.conv;

    public  B b;

    // We can't just use sizeof here because we want the size of the
    // instance, not the reference.
    private void[__traits(classInstanceSize, B)] b_space;

    this() {
        b = emplace!B(b_space);
    }
}
```

Comment: You still need to account for alignment though and in that case the `scoped!B` template will have all that already implemented.

Comment: I want to say that although this answer has been accepted I too think that a `scoped!B` based solution would be better in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options:

First you can make `B` a struct type, if you don't need the ref semantics then just don't make it a class in the first place.

Otherwise you can use [`scoped!B`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.scoped) to allocate `b` in place.

```d
import std.typecons;
class A
{
    public int c;
    public scoped!B b;
}
```

In both cases the descructor of B will be called when the A that contains it gets destroyed.

Comment: scoped won't allocate in place, it's only a wrapper struct arround the class for deterministic destruction

Comment: Does using struct or scoped!B come with any implications? Does scoped!B guarentee that the garbage collector will not be called? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @cym13 [I beg to differ](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/typecons.d#L6082) it is a struct with a static array the size of the instance+alignment.

Comment: @ChristianVeenman `scoped!B` will get cleaned up when at the same time the A containing it gets cleaned up.

Comment: @cym13 The docs even explicitly says it will avoid the overhead of `new` That's not something that a wrapper around the ref can do.

Answer (score 0):

`scoped!T` in the answer above is a function, not a type; the given example will therefore not work. The reason is that classes must be initialized with a constructor call.

As a workaround, use `typeof()` and initialize the member in the class' constructor:

```
import std.typecons;
class B { }
class A {
    public int c;
    public typeof(scoped!B()) b;
    this() {
        this.b = scoped!B();
    }
}
```

Note that although the line in the constructor looks like an assignment, it is correctly interpreted as a construction.